# About the dual variable's space in Fenchel's duality

Tags: duality-theorems

My friends,

I have a question about Fenchel's duality.

---

**Background**: According to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%27s_duality_theorem), in Fenchel duality, we have the following theorem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{+ \infty\}$ and $g: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{+ \infty\}$ be convex functions and $A: X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear map. Then, the Fenchel problems are:
$$
p^* = \inf_{x \in X} \{ f(x) + g(Ax) \} \\
d^* = \sup_{y^* \in Y^*} \{ -f^*(A^*y^*) - g^*(-y^*) \}
$$
and $p^* = d^*$ if strong duality holds.

**My question is:**

In the above duality, if $X = [0,1]^n$ (in other words, each $x \in X$ is a $n$-dimensional vector with each dimension's value as 0~1), what will be the space Y*?

Particularly, will this $Y^*$ space be non-negative (in other words, should each $y^*$ be some non-negative vector)?

---

Thanks a lot for your attention and very appreciate it if you can kindly help me with this!

Vincent

Comment: $[0, 1]^n$ is not a Banach space.

Comment: @Qiaochu: thanks for correcting the error. Let's say, if $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but in practice assume $x$ is some $n$-dimensional vector with each dimension's value as 0~1, then is there any way to know whether those $y^*$ should be non-negative?